# How to resize footer text with the Grover Gem in Ruby on Rails 5.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

```
  def pdf_render(format, file_name, view, orientation, page_size = 'A4', footer="")
@file_name = "#{file_name} [#{date_time_now}]"
html = render_to_string({
                          template: view,
                          layout: 'pdf.html.slim'
                        })
style_tag_options = [
  {
    content: 'footer{font-size: 16px}'
  }
]
options = {
  format: page_size,
  landscape: orientation == 'Landscape',
  emulate_media: 'screen',
  display_url: "#{request.protocol.to_s}#{request.env['HTTP_HOST'].to_s}",
  footer_template: footer,
  style_tag_options: style_tag_options
}
grover = Grover.new(
  html,
  options
).to_pdf

format.pdf do
  send_data(grover, filename: "#{@file_name}.pdf")
end
end
```

This is the function I am using to render the pdf for a form. But the footer element is breaking and too small to read. I have not been able to increase the font size and do anything using the **Grover** gem which is being used everywhere in the system in Ruby on Rails 5.2; my controller code is given below:

```
def m_6_3

add_breadcrumb 'Mushak 6.3'

render('mushaks/filters/m_6_3') && return if (params[:sale].nil? || !params[:sale][:id].present?)

add_breadcrumb 'Preview'

@sale = Sale.find(params[:sale][:id])
@service_charge_column = true if @sale.company.has_vms_api
footer = "<footer>#{date_time_now}</footer><footer>This challan is system generated. Hence, no seal is required.</footer>"
print = PrintCount.find_or_create_by(creator: @sale, action: 'm_6_3')
@copy_print = print.count > 0

if params[:format].eql? 'pdf'
  @type = 'pdf'
  @copy_print = increase_print_count(@sale, 'm_6_3')
else
  @type = 'html'
end

if params[:commit].eql?(ApplicationRecord::PDF_BUTTON_TEXT)
  redirect_to m_6_3_mushaks_path(sale: { id: @sale.id }, format: 'pdf' )
end

@sale_items = @sale.sale_items
@company = @sale.company

@sum = @sale_items
           .select('sum(total) as total, sum(total_in_foreign_currency) as total_in_foreign_currency, sum(vat) as vat, sum(sd) as sd, sum(net_total) as net_total')
           .first

respond_to do |format|
  format.html if @type == 'html'
  pdf_render format, "Mushak-6.3-#{@sale.number}", 'mushaks/m_6_3.html.slim', @company&.report_preference&.m_6_3_orientation || 'Portrait', (@company&.report_preference&.m_6_3_page_size || 'A4' if @type == 'pdf'), footer
end 
end
```

Grover gem configuration can be found below:

```
Grover.configure do |config|
  config.options = {
    display_header_footer: true,
    margin: {
      top: '0.05in',
      bottom: '0.05in',
      left: '0.4in',
      right: '0.4in'
    },
    user_agent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0',
    viewport: {
      width: 640,
      height: 480
    },
    prefer_css_page_size: true,
    bypass_csp: true,
    media_features: [{ name: 'prefers-color-scheme', value: 'dark' }],
    extra_http_headers: { 'Accept-Language': 'en-US' },
    timeout: 0,
    cache: false,
    launch_args: ['--font-render-hinting=medium', '--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox', '--disable-dev-shm-usage'],
    wait_until: 'networkidle2',
    print_background: true
  }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, there are some default css class and ids from chromium which can be used to correctly set the header and footer. The documentation of puppeteer and Grover isn't that great. So, I found an issue on their repository which has the solution in the link [here](https://github.com/Studiosity/grover/issues/55).